# How to "hit" bashiok with Rakanishu's blade

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I got the Rakanishu's Blade and immediately after saw Bashiok(apparently I am pretty lucky based on my searches). I knew I had to hit Bashiok so I equipped it on my WD but I didn't know which skill I needed to use to "hit" him. I used poison dart and I didn't get the achievement.

Do I just try to run out of mana so I will have to attack him melee style? Is there a better way of disabling the skills?

Comment: Try changing skills and hit him during the cooldown?

Comment: Also, the right answer is probably to use elective mode and drag your skill off the toolbar - but using CD be another way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to hit him with a 'normal' melee attack.

The easiest way to do this is to use Elective Mode and drag the skill you currently have bound to the left or right mouse button off of your bar, then go click on Bashiok.

If you can't do so, say, because you're trying to preserve an NV stack or something, your best bet is to use up all of your resources and keep clicking after they're expended -  be careful you don't kill him before you're out of mana in this case though!